# Runtime Error due to Exceeding character limit in a string

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, limit

The code is intended to solve the below problem.

> For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings.Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes

*Source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity/problem*

My Code:

```
def stringSimilarity(s):   #function which does the work for a string <s>
    suffix=[]              #to store all suffixes for a given string
    similarity=[]          #to store all similarities corresponding to alL--
                           #--suffixes of one given string
                                        
    for i in range(len(s)): #creating a list of suffixes
        suffix.append(s[i:])
                           #considering one element in a given suffix
    for i in range(len(suffix)):
        sim=0              #similarity count for a given suffix
                           #comparison of a suffix with string    
        for j in range(len(suffix[i])):
            if suffix[i][j]==s[j]:
                sim+=1     #similarity count increases
            else:
                break      #cancel the loop if condition didn't match for-- 
                           #--first character of the taken suffix
                    
        similarity.append(sim)      
    return sum(similarity)     

t=int(input())              #no of test cases
solution=[]                 #for storing results for all test cases

for i in range(t):
    str=input()
    solution.append(stringSimilarity(str))
                                    
                            #displaying results for all test cases accordingly
    for i in range(len(solution)):
    print(solution[i])
```

The code encounters a run-time error for larger strings(taken as input) with no. of characters in the order of several thousands.

The code works fine for "smaller" strings.
I tried to convert the strings and suffixes to lists to do the required comparisons but encountered the same problem.

P.S
I think this has something to do with the character/memory limits,overflows but am not aware of solutions to such cases. Please help me with the modifications needed in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: The expected solution is better than O(n^2) (your solution). Have a look at [Z-Algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107)

Comment: @DeepakGouda  I seek modifications in the code which would resolve the run-time error with large strings. Z-Algorithm however, deals with the same data types and loops and would encounter the same error. btw, Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n^2) both in time and space complexity. Your code must be exceeding the memory limit resulting in the runtime error. However Z-algorithm is O(n) time and space complexity. Modifications to your code will not improve the space complexity from quadratic scale.